# Home page for website in heroku is not set to index.html

Tags: html, github, heroku

Title says it all, so basically I have a website from github that I imported into heroku. When I test the website out with the github page preview, everything works just fine. But when I launch the site with heroku, the home page is set to an entirely different page instead of index.html

(Also, there's only one github page branch which is the master branch if that helps, I'm new to this)

So, is there something wrong with the website code, or is there some way to set a page as the home page on heroku? All I need to know is the answer to that question. *Thank you!*

Comment: > We can trick Heroku to deploy a static site by including 1 dynamic file.  please see https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku